# Delphi Sort a TList with TRecord syntax

Tags: delphi

I have the following code related to a record and list. Online examples and tutorials appear to be lacking in this area.

implementation

```
type
   TRecordRGB = record
   Name:String;
   Red,Green,Blue:Integer;
 end;

Var
  recordRGB:TRecordRGB;
  rgbList: TList<TRecordRGB>;
Begin
  rgbList := TList<TRecordRGB>.Create;
  CreateList(rgbList);
  rgbList.Sort(TRecordRGB.Name);
```

The Build gives me the following error for my syntax.
for the following code:
rgbList.Sort(TRecordRGB.Name);

[dcc32 Error] UTColorUtility.pas(117): E2096 Method identifier expected

What is the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply your own comparison function:

```
list := TList<TRecordRGB>.Create;
try

  // populate list

  list.Sort(
    TComparer<TRecordRGB>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: TRecordRGB): Integer
      begin
        Result := CompareText(Left.Name, Right.Name) // case-insensitive comparison
      end
    )
  );

finally
  list.Free;
end;
```